# List entries of documents in a section grouped by checkbox

Tags: entries, assets, checkboxes

I'm trying to list entries in a section which are documents. Those documents are grouped by checkbox. I'd like to list the document title and the asset in the entry's url. I only want to list assets which have a specific checkbox ticket.

I was able to output and group the assets by checkbox, but I'm struggling to find that entries asset url. Any thoughts?

This is what I have so far:

```
{% set entries = craft.entries.section('documentLibrary')%}

{# get all checkbox options #}
{% set options = entries.first().documentType.options %}
{% set assets = entry.documents %}

 {% for entry in entries if entry.documentType.contains('Report') %}
    {% for asset in assets %}
       <a href="{{ asset.url }}" type="application/pdf;" class="list-group-item active">{{ entry.title }}</a>
    {% endfor %}
 {% endfor %}
```

Unfortunately as expected the `{{ asset.url }}` returns the url of the entry and not of the asset documents which is attached to the entry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your assets variable is defined outside the entries loop so it is still referring to the page entry. If you move it inside the loop it should work as expected.

```
{% set entries = craft.entries.section('documentLibrary') %}
{% for entry in entries if entry.documentType.contains('Report') %}
    {% for asset in entry.documents %}
       <a href="{{ asset.url }}" type="application/pdf;" class="list-group-item active">{{ entry.title }}</a>
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Rather than doing this manually however, you might also have a look at the [group](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/filters#group) filter, which can group the entries array by document type.

```
{% set entries = craft.entries.section('documentLibrary').find() %}
{% set groupedEntries = entries|group('documentType') %}

{% for type, entriesByType in groupedEntries %}
    <h2>{{ type }}</h2>
    <ul>
        {% for entry in entriesByType %}
            {% for asset in entry.documents %}
                <a href="{{ asset.url }}" type="application/pdf;" class="list-group-item active">{{ entry.title }}</a>
            {% endfor %}
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% endfor %}
```

Note: Also if each 'document' only contain one and only one 'asset' (i.e. pdf), then you can also get rid of the asset loop and just use `{{ entry.document.first.url }}`.